# Centering non-text content in a center division?

Tags: html, css

In my page, I need to make something that looks like this, with a center division with images of different widths all center-aligned within the division (the lines won't be visible, that's just to make it easier to explain):

```
---------------------------------------
|           |   IMAGE 1   |           |
|  <stuff>  |   IMAGE 2   |  <stuff>  |
|           |  IMAGE 123  |           |
---------------------------------------
```

There's a parent division for the whole "pseudo-table", and three divisions for each pseudo-column.  However, no matter what I try, it seems to always look like this, where the left edge of the images aligns with each other:

```
---------------------------------------
|           |  IMAGE 1    |           |
|  <stuff>  |  IMAGE 2    |  <stuff>  |
|           |  IMAGE 123  |           |
---------------------------------------
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="leftcol">STUFF HERE</div>
  <div class="centercol">
    <img="URL HERE"><br>
    <img="URL HERE"><br>
    <img="URL HERE">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">STUFF HERE</div>
</div>
```

For my CSS, I have pared it down for the sake of troubleshooting to:

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.leftcol {
}
.centercol {
  justify-items:center;
}
.rightcol {
}
```

I've also tried `align-items:center` to the same lack of results.  Any ideas?

Comment: _Proper_ [mre] first of all, please.

Comment: Please share MINIMAL amount of code that reproduces your current situation. Otherwise, we cannot help you

Comment: `justify-items:center;` only applies to flex **parents**. Try adding `text-align: center` to your `centercol`

Comment: Ya this is an easy thin to make a codepen of. Go to code pen.io I believe to make an mvp

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex`, `align-items: center` and `flex-direction: column` to the center column div:

```css
.parent {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.leftcol {
}
.centercol {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.rightcol {
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="leftcol">STUFF HERE</div>
  <div class="centercol">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100"><br>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/100"><br>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/120/100">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">STUFF HERE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also imbricate flex and grid to allow also X,Y centering on each columns : example

```css
.parent {
  display:flex;
}
.parent>div {
  flex:1;
  display:grid;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  
  gap:0.25em;/* optional */
}
/* see what is going on */
div div {
  border:solid 1px;
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,transparent 50%, rgba(200,100,100,0.1) 50%),linear-gradient(0deg,transparent 50%, rgba(100,0,100,0.1) 50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="leftcol">STUFF HERE</div>
  <div class="centercol">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50"><br>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/40"><br>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/60/30">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcol">STUFF HERE</div>
</div>
```